# How to check if file size is not incrementing ,if not then kill the $$ of script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tail

I am trying to figure out a way to monitor the files I am dumping from my script. If there is no increment seen in child files then kill my script.

I am doing this to free up the resources when not needed. Here is what I think of , but I think my apporch is going to add burden to CPU. Can anyone please suggest more efficent way of doing this?

Below script is suppose to poll in every 15 sec and collect two file size of same file, if the size of the two samples are same then exit.

```
checkUsage() {
  while true; do
    sleep 15
    fileSize=$(stat -c%s $1)

    sleep 10;
    fileSizeNew=$(stat -c%s $1)

    if [ "$fileSize" == "$fileSizeNew" ]; then
      echo -e  "[Error]: No activity noted on this window from 5 sec. Exiting..."
      kill -9 $$
    fi
  done
}
```

And I am planning to call it as follow (in background):

```
checkUsage /var/log/messages &
```

I can also get solution if, someone suggest how to monitor tail command and if nothing printing on tail then exit. NOT SURE WHY PEOPLE ARE CONFUSED. End goal of this question is to ,check if the some file is edited in last 15 seconds. If not exit or throw some error.

I have achived this by above script,but I don't know if this is the smartest way of achiveing this. I have asked this question to know views from other if there is any alternative way or better way of doing it.

Comment: What is the final goal ? Sounds like a XY problem ...

Comment: final goal is to ensure that ,if /var/log/messages are not incrementing its size in ever 15 sec then kill my script.

Comment: The above script will check the file in every 10 seconds though as you have put `sleep 10;` in between `fileSize` and `fileSizeNew`

Comment: I agree, this will take sample of two files with difference of 10 sec. Howver this polling will happen in every 15 sec.

Comment: Where do you think the burden is?  The `sleep` will not consume any resources and the two `stat` calls are hard to avoid for what you are trying to accomplish.  Where do you see a problem?  How much resources is a solution allowed to use in order to be acceptable?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour and what is the problem. The only thing i see is that you are not calling the `checkUsage` function anywhere. @user5584716

Comment: The loop totals 25 seconds and the message says 5 seconds.  Maybe think harder about what the timings should be.

Comment: The `echo` says "Error" where you're actually gracefully exiting.. ;)

Comment: Well, honestly I am ok with this solution.Its working for me. But not sure if this is the smartest way of doing this. Here I put this question to know any alternate or smarter way.   Please do not go on display messages....Its still under development. :)

Comment: I will call checkUsage function later in script in background mode.

Comment: Might as well check the mtime with stat. Checking filesize is okay, logically speaking, but it's just an odd way of saying the thing hasn't changed, while mtime is much more direct.

Comment: An inactive script or program is likely to be idle, so won't eat CPU resources and could be swapped out. So **why do you ask?** and what is your real goal. Pleas **edit your question** (currently very unclear) to improve it. Give much more context

Comment: @user5584716 : Try to respond to comments as fast as possible. That is fair way of doing it, if you're looking for a smarter way to do it. Please mention that in the question that `this one works and is it the best?`

Comment: @sjsam OP can respond to comments as quickly or slowly as he pleases. What is the rush?

Comment: @arco444 : I agree but if he responds as fast as he can, any clarifications regarding the question can easily be made.

Comment: I am sorry for delay in repsonding. I just wanted some shorter way of doing this. If you all feel this is a acceptable or best way of doing then I agree and accept the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would based the check on file modification time instead of size, so something like this (untested code):

```
checkUsage() {
  while true; do
    # Test if file mtime is 'second arg' seconds older than date, default to 10 seconds
    if [ $(( $(date +"%s") - $(stat -c%Y /var/log/message) )) -gt ${2-10} ]; then
      echo -e  "[Error]: No activity noted on this window from ${2-10} sec. Exiting..."
      return 1
    fi
    #Sleep 'first arg' second, 15 seconds by default
    sleep ${1-15}
  done
}
```

The idea is to compare the file mtime with current time, if it's greater than second argument seconds, print the message and return.

And then I would call it like this later (or with no args to use defaults):

```
[ checkusage 20 10 ] || exit 1
```

Which would exit the script with code 1 as when the function return from it's infinite loop (as long as the file is modified)

Edit: reading me again, the target file could be a parameter too, to allow a better reuse of the function, left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

If on Linux, in a local file system (Ext4, BTRFS, ...) -not a network file system- then you could consider [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities: something could be triggered when some file or directory changes or is accessed.

In particular, you might have some incron job thru [incrontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) file; maybe it could communicate with some other job ...

<sup>PS. I am not sure to understand what you really want to do...</sup>

Comment: End goal of this question is to ,check if the some file is edited in last 15 seconds. If not exit or throw some error. 

I have achived this by above script,but I don't know if this is the smartest way of achiveing this. I have asked this question to know views from other if there is any alternative way or better way of doing it.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to check if there are any changes made in some X file in last 15 seconds. If any chances are made, then ignore and keep checking in after some time. However if there are no changes made in file X , then exit or throw error.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose an external programme is modifying `/var/log/messages`.

If this is the case, below is my script (with minor changes to yours)

```
#Bash script to monitor changes to file
#!/bin/bash
checkUsage() # Note that U is in caps
{
while true
do
        sleep 15
        fileSize=$(stat -c%s $1)
        sleep 10;
        fileSizeNew=$(stat -c%s $1)

        if [ "$fileSize" == "$fileSizeNew" ]
        then
           echo -e  "[Notice : ] no changes noted in $1 : gracefully exiting"
           exit # previously this was kill -9 $$
           # changing this to exit would end the program gracefully.
           # use kill -9  to kill a process which is not under your control.
           # kill -9 sends the SIGKILL signal.
        fi

done
}
checkUsage $1 # I have added this to your script

#End of the script
```

Save the script as `checkusage` and run it like :

```
./checkusage /var/log/messages &
```

**Edit :**

Since you're looking for better solutions I would suggest `inotifywait`, thanks for the suggestion from the other answerer.

Below would be my code :

```
while inotifywait -t 10 -q -e modify $1 >/dev/null
do
    sleep 15 # as you said the polling would happen in 15 seconds.
done
echo "Script exited gracefully : $1 has not been changed"
```

Below are the details from the [inotifywait manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)

> -t <seconds>, --timeout <seconds> Exit if an appropriate event has not occurred within <seconds> seconds. If <seconds> is zero (the default),
>   wait indefinitely for an event.
>
> -e <event>, --event <event> Listen for specific event(s) only. The events which can be listened for are listed in the EVENTS section.
>   This option can be specified more than once. If omitted, all events
>   are listened for.
>
> -q, --quiet If specified once, the program will be less verbose. Specifically, it will not state when it has completed establishing all
>   inotify watches.
>
> modify(Event) A watched file or a file within a watched directory was
>   written to.

**Notes**

You might have to install the `inotify-tools` first to make use of the `inotifywait` command. Check the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) page at Github.

Comment: Those changes are *very* minor... What did you do other than changing the indenting and the printed message? Why `kill` and not `exit`?

Comment: In fact I meant exit would be graceful and kill -9 would be forceful. Pls see the edit.

Comment: `gracefully exiting` `kill -9` hahaha

Comment: You  have my upvote for the edit part. Drawbacks are: 1) the need of extra package/compilation which may or may not fit all cases and 2) Won't work on network filesystems. But it's a good alternative indeed.